# how to make jQuery work in tumblr

Tags: jquery

this is the jQuery code in my script.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#NEW').delay(250).fadeIn(1000);
$('#MEDIA').delay(850).fadeIn(1000);
$('#NEWB').delay(1600).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

where and how do I put these codes in my html? I know i need to have script tags in the head section. But what are the specifics? as far as the proper `<script ref="...
">` tags and where do I put these codes exactly.

Comment: You put them in the main template head section

Comment: also, id's should be unique and not used for multiple things. Not sure what you're planning on doing with those that you have, just making sure :)

Comment: well i'm trying to make an interactive tumblr blog. As you can see i'm a newb. So my tumblr blog will be anything-related to digital medida (design/industry/stories/business/onlinemarketing etc..)

I am on the very early stages of my custom template. I want to test out this specific jQuery if it's working. I dont know the proper placement and coding of jQuery in my html file

Comment: I've updated my answer for you. Just remember that ID's (#NEW, #MEDIA etc) should always be unique. If they are being used more than once, use a class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to 'customise theme' when logged in then 'edit html' which should be located at the top and then paste relevant codes between `<head>` and `</head>` tags

For example:

```
<head>
    <title>{Title}</title>
    {block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{PortraitURL-128}"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

The above example requires you to upload script.js to tumblr's server and grab the absolute URL they give you, below is an inline example, which will probably be better for you if you are new to theming:

```
<head>
    <title>{Title}</title>
    {block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{PortraitURL-128}"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#NEW').delay(250).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#MEDIA').delay(850).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#NEWB').delay(1600).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: thank you. So as far as those codes I have posted. will the go in between the  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> tag?

Comment: Tumblr requires template files to be uploaded seperately, so you would need to upload your script.js file, and grab the absolute url to it OR paste the code between the script type tag, without the src. Let me update the scenario for you

Comment: Updated the examples for you

Comment: wow, you made that so easy. =D I need to understand more what "block" and "meta descriptions" are and how they work. I have no idea what they are.

Comment: do you know any newb/user friendly html editors where I can preview my  page as i work along?

Comment: That's just how tumblr pops in their codes. The {} brackets are hooks that their backend looks for to replace with your content. Theming tumblr is brilliant, well worth getting into. The answer i've given you should do the trick, so please accept when you can :)

Comment: If you're on about your tumblr theme, you're best making an account just for testing tumblr themes, as it will be best to use their system. {block} etc won't work unless on tumblr's system. That's what i do anyways. But in terms of actual coding programs, my favourite is sublime text 2

Comment: ah I see the logic. Tumblr has their block and meta codes that only applies to them correct? So it wouldn't be useful as far as making any other website of my own. For now I tend to build a customized tumblr blog so I will learn these codes. thank you sir

Comment: Exactly mate, it's their templating system that uses those codes so open up a test account and develop to your hearts content. Theming tumblr is pretty simple when you know how :)

Comment: Sir, is there anyway of contacting you for other future questions? I would like to reach out to you again

Comment: If you go on my profile (click my name) you will see a link to my portfolio, you can contact me via that :)